# Which C++ header includes which other headers?

Tags: c++, stream, include, static-libraries

I am confused of which standard library include which other once. I heard that `iostream` includes `ostream` or something like that. Unfortunately I couldn't find an overview. That's why I ask now.

My program uses the following libraries: string, `fstream`, `iostream`, `sstream`, `streambuf`. Because they provide related functionality I wonder if any of these includes another of them already. In this case I could get rid of the redundant includes.

**Is there a overview out there indicating which standard library includes which?** or
**Which of the libraries user by my program are redundant?**

Comment: You mean headers, yes? Never rely on any including any other. Always explicitly included the ones you need. There are no guarantees about which include which others (Edit: it appears I am wrong here with regards to `c++11`).

Comment: Is this a C question? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: This is different in C and in C++. Make up your mind which one you're asking about.

Comment: Consider using ["include what you use"](https://include-what-you-use.org/) tool in your build, to take care of these things consistently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ provides no guarantees in general for any sort of recursive inclusion. It is your responsibility to *always include all headers that you need*. Similarly, it does not guarantee that any particular standard library header is *not* included. (For example, your implementation could legally always include all standard library headers!) That's why-and-because everything is in the `std` namespace.

(I believe there's a special provision for the C library headers - I think you *won't* get names in the global namespace unless you explicitly include those headers.)

Some headers do have specific requirements; for example, in C++11 (but not before) it is required that `<iostream>` include both `<ostream>` and `<istream>`. But that's just one specific case.

Comment: 1. several C++11 headers are required to `#include <initializer_list>`; I think that's the only such requirement other than `<iostream>`, as you mentioned. 2. the C++ <cxxx> headers are allowed to insert names into the global namespace, and required to put names into `std`; the C headers <xxx.h> are allowed to insert names into `std` and required to put names into the global namesapace.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I know, but that's not the point. The thing is that any header should be allowed to silently include `<cstdio>`, but if a header does so, I believe it is *not* permitted to put `printf` in the global namespace, only in `std`. Only if you explicitly include `<stdio.h>` do you get it guaranteed, and if you explicitly include `<cstdio>` you may or may not get `printf` in the global namespace.

Comment: I see: your point was much more subtle than I thought it was. I don't think that separation is required, but I don't have a citation for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on any headers being included by any other headers. It's best to explicitly include everything you need. That way, if you change the compiler, you can be sure not to break compilation, in case the new compiler doesn't have the same header include structure.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/iostream/ iostream is inherited from ostream and istream.

Answer (score 1):

My rule: `#include` what you are using. If you are using `std::string`, you need to `#include <string>`. If you are using `std::cout`, you need to `#include <iostream>`. If you are using a file stream, `#include <fstream>`. And so on.

That you *might* get `std::string` for "free" from some of those other system headers that you include is irrelevant. Don't depend on those behind the scenes includes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried of retundant includes they are handled via macros like

#ifndef MACRO_NAME
   #define MACRO_NAME

#endif

So you dont need to worry about multiple includes i guess.